# Variable in class is resetting by itself

Tags: c++, variables, arduino

I am working on an LED Fader for the Arduino. For this I wrote a class which defines everything. But since yesterday I have a problem and I can't solve it. 
So far here is my code:

```
class LED {
    int pins[4];
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int task = 1;
    int taskgoal = 255;
  public:
    void newTask() {
      ...
    }
    void newGoal() {
      ...
    }
    boolean taskFinished() {
      ...
    }
    void runTask() {
      if (taskFinished()) {
        newTask();
        newGoal();
        cout << "New Task and new Goal.\n";
      }
      int current;
      switch (task) {
        ...
      }
      if (current < taskgoal) {
        switch (task) {
          case 1:
            cout << r << "+1" << "\n";
            this->redefine(this->r + 1, this->g, this->b);
            cout << r << "+1" << "\n";
            break;
          case 2:
            cout << g << "+1" << "\n";
            this->redefine(this->g, this->g + 1, this->b);
            break;
          case 3:
            cout << b << "+1" << "\n";
            this->redefine(this->r, this->g, this->b + 1);
            break;
        }
      } else if (current > taskgoal) {
        ...
      }
      analogWrite(pins[0], this->r);
      analogWrite(pins[1], this->g);
      analogWrite(pins[2], this->b);
      return;
    }
    void ledinit(int p[]) {
      this->r = random(1, 255);
      this->g = random(1, 255);
      this->b = random(1, 255);
      for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        pins[i] = p[i];
        pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
      }
      pins[3] = p[3];
      analogWrite(pins[0], this->r);
      analogWrite(pins[1], this->g);
      analogWrite(pins[2], this->b);
      analogWrite(pins[3], LOW);
      newTask();
      newGoal();
      runTask();
      return;
    }
    void redefine(int rr, int gg, int bb) {
      r = rr;
      g = gg;
      b = bb;
      return;
    }
};
std::vector< LED >leds;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  LED l1;
  int l1pins[4] = {11, 9, 8, 10};
  l1.ledinit(l1pins);
  leds.push_back(l1);
}

void loop() {
  for (LED l : leds) {
    l.runTask();
    cout << "Run Task" << "\n";
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

(Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pQMEkG1a)
In Line 76 I try to add 1 to the r value with my function redefine. I also tried it directly with `this->r++;` or `this->r += 1;` but all has the same result. It will add the 1 to the r variable. But at the next loop, it is again the same value like at the beginning. This is how the output looks like:

```
Run Task
45+1
46+1
Run Task
45+1
46+1
Run Task
45+1
46+1
```

But why is it 45 every time? I think it is a very easy fault by me but I can't find it.

Comment: First  learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then put that MCVE *in* the question body, copy-pasted, as text. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post your code into the question. Links can become invalid over time.

Comment: Can you edit the pasted example to include the pastebin link (http://pastebin.com/pQMEkG1a) and the loop-method?

Comment: I added the pastebin link to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I would expect that your problem lies within `for (LED l : leds)`

This range-based for loops over a vector of LEDs, takes from each element a copy, on which you will run the task.

I would suggest writing the following: `for (LED &l : leds)` to prevent the copy.

As it looks like your compiler supports C++11, you might want to prevent similar issues in the future by adding following member function to the class LED: `LED(const LED &) = delete;` and possibly a few others from [the rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). This will prevent any copy from the led. Possibly you will require some move-constructor in order to add the LEDs in the vector.

Comment: Thanks this is working. But if i add `LED(const LED &) = delete;` i can't init my led variable.

Comment: I tried to add the rule of five like this http://pastebin.com/605Q5yKj but it is not working. Maybe i misunderstood something.

Comment: I would guess that this should work, though don't forget that you actually have to move: v.push_back(std::move(led));